# NAudio MediaFoundationReader ReadFail On Windows Server 2012R2 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

My local computer OS is Win 7SP1 64bit.

The Server is Windows Server 2012R2 64bit.

I use NAudio to Convert AAC file into WAV file:

```
        MediaFoundationReader mfReader =
                new MediaFoundationReader(path);
        string tempfilename = Guid.NewGuid() + ".wav";

        MemoryStream otStream = new MemoryStream();
        WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(otStream, mfReader);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tempfilename, Encoding.UTF8));
        Response.BinaryWrite(otStream.ToArray());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

It works fine on my own computer,but throw exception on server.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): 对 COM 组件的调用返回了错误 HRESULT E_FAIL。
>      在 NAudio.MediaFoundation.MediaFoundationInterop.MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(String pwszURL, IMFAttributes pAttributes, IMFSourceReader& ppSourceReader)

I have already installed the "Meida Foundation" And "Desktop Experience" features on server ,but it still dont work.

Have I missed small configuration? or just NAudio doesn't support working on servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot mention a detail that "path" parameter is a URL Link,not a local file's name.

So,the error actually caused by a network 404 since the Server's network environment is much more restricted.

Then I changed the URL which server can reach,and it threw a different error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC00D36C4): 不支持给定的 URL 的字节流类型。 (异常来自 HRESULT:0xC00D36C4)

So I tried to use "WebClient" to download the AAC file first,and read it from local disk.

It finaly worked!

In Conclusion：NAudio sure can work on server 2012,but some of its feature may be restricted.